Is there any strong logic behind the formula for the slope and curvature loadings in Nelso Siegel model?
The Nelson Siegel model is given as follow:
$$
y(\tau) = \beta_0 + \beta_1 \cdot \frac{1 - e^{-\lambda \tau}}{\lambda \tau} + \beta_2 \cdot \left( \frac{1 - e^{-\lambda \tau}}{\lambda \tau} - e^{-\lambda \tau} \right)
$$
I understand that for the betas:

$\beta_0$ represents the long-term level of interest rates, indicating the yield for very long maturities.
$\beta_1$ reflects the short-term slope of the yield curve, capturing the difference between short-term and long-term interest rates.
$\beta_2$ accounts for the medium-term curvature, representing the hump or dip in the yield curve that is not explained by the level and slope components.
$\lambda $ determines the decay rate of the exponential terms, influencing the sensitivity of the model to different maturities.

And for the loadings:

$\frac{1 - e^{-\lambda \tau}}{\lambda \tau}$  starts at 1 when τ=0 and decays monotonically to 0 as τ increases, allowing to have a different impact from the long-end to the short end
$\frac{1 - e^{-\lambda \tau}}{\lambda \tau} - e^{-\lambda \tau}$ starts at 0 when τ=0, increases to a maximum, and then decays back to 0 as τ increases.

I also understand that the shapes loadings "closely" the 3 first components of the PCA - however I was wondering:

Is there any strong justification behind the formula for the loadings of the slope and the curvature apart from the ones previously explained? Because it seems that a lot of functions could match these same characteristics.
The impact of the lambda on the slope is slightly less obvious than it is for the curvature to me and I am not really sure to get why we get some $\lambda$ in it.


Is there logic behind just the first 3 principal components of (most) yield curves having nice geometric interpretations and explaining most of the the curve variance?

I found this article that could be interesting for your q. (if it is):  https://www.newyorkfed.org/research/staff_reports/sr884 - "Deconstructing the Yield Curve". It  finds the 3 first PC on various sets of data from Treasury Yields to... global surface temperature. Quoting: "Remarkably again, the loadings are very similar in shape to those estimated from maturity-ordered financial assets. This provides preliminary evidence that the high explained variation and the particular shape of PC loadings are reflective of the strong local correlation (i.e., smooth curve) across these ordered data"
